# PayPal credit card button hides PayPal standard button

Tags: paypal, credit-card

We are using PayPal with the default button and with visa and MasterCard buttons. When we click on a credit card button the default PayPal button is hidden. Is there a way to avoid this? We don't want that user has to refresh the page to see again the choice for PayPal payment method.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to avoid it, PayPal is intentionally making use of that screen real estate.

You could allow the user to trigger a `.close()` of the PayPal button (save a reference to it before you `.render()`) and so then create a fresh one in its place, if you really want to avoid them having to do a page refresh.